# Pass the value of a props from a function to render() in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am making a get request from my React App to my backend. The call is successfull and I am able to receive the values from backend. However, I am not able to set the value to the front end DOM.
Here is how my class currently looks:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getData();
    }
    renderProds(){
        const data = this.props.products;
        if(data){
            data.map((e)=>{
                return (
                   <Product 
                      name={e.name}
                      desc={e.desc}
                   />
                );
            });
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
          <div>{this.renderProds()}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've made sure that my **Product** component is imported correctly and it is accepting the props `name` and `desc`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return something from your `renderProds` methods. Try this:

```
renderProds(){
        const data = this.props.products;
        if(data){
            return data.map((e)=>{ // return computed value
                return (
                   <Product 
                      name={e.name}
                      desc={e.desc}
                   />
                );
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is it any different from my return statement?

Comment: `data.map` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. So the return state in `data.map` returns element of the new array, not the return value of `renderProds` function.